# EntityManager in Transactional CDI bean

Tags: jpa, cdi, java-ee-7

I have an EntityManager associated with my persistence unit (myPU).
I have the following code which represents a generic DataAccessObject which I want to use in order to execute tasks in a new transaction (requires-new).
This DataAccessObject gets injected into an EJB and its unique method gets invoked in a while loop.
Another EntityManager instance referencing the same persistence unit exists in the EJB.
I'm expecting that at every method invocation of my DataAccessObject instance, a new transaction gets created and committed (or rollbacked) according to the following code.

The problem is that i get a transaction required exception. What am i missing?

```
@Dependent
@ManagedBean
public class DataAccessObject {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataAccessObject.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "scheduler")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackOn = Exception.class)
    public void executeInNewTransaction(TransactionalTask transactionalTask) throws TransactionalException {

        Throwable exception = null;
        try {

            logger.debug(" A new transaction has been created for transactional task: \"", transactionalTask, "\".");
            transactionalTask.onExecute(entityManager);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            exception = e;
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {

            Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> constraintViolation = e.getConstraintViolations();
            logger.error("Exception during bean validation:");
            if (constraintViolation != null) {
                for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : constraintViolation) {
                    
                    logger.error(String.format("%s=\"%s\" error: %s", violation.getPropertyPath(), violation.getInvalidValue(), violation.getMessage()));
                }
            }
            exception = e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {

            exception = e;

        } finally {

            if (exception != null || transactionalTask.mustRollBack()) {

                throw new TransactionRolledBackException("Transaction is being rolled back for transactional task: \"" + transactionalTask + "\".", exception);
            } else {

                logger.debug(" Transaction has been committed successfully for transactional task: \"", transactionalTask, "\".");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the class from where you call executeInNewTransaction?

Comment: Hi Simon! thanks for you answer, i'm posting my answer in a few hours since i'm at office now. By the way it looks like a persistence exception was thrown in a previous "find"/"persist" operation and the code just catched the exception without logging it. I would ask, at this point, does a persistence exception/sql exception close the current transaction?